# C# XNA: Use Custom Mouse Animated Cursor .ani

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am trying to use custom animated cursor in Xna game.

I tried to load the .ani cursor to content but it's wont build so i removed it and tried to use it from local disk . but its also wont to accept .ani format.

```
            using(System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "//Data//Cursor//Normal.ani"))
            {
                this.cursorTex = Texture2D.FromStream(this.GraphicsDevice, stream.BaseStream);
            }
```

but i got an exception says file format not accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Texture2D.FromStream` only supports `.bmp`, `.gif`, `.jpg`, `.png`, `.tif` and `.dds` file formats. [According to the inline source documentation](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/3e92fc7bff7b4c32edf1314e143a4b7de4fab161/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/Texture2D.cs#L271):

```
        /// Creates a Texture2D from a stream, supported formats bmp, gif, jpg, png, tif and dds (only for simple textures).
        /// May work with other formats, but will not work with tga files.
```

It seems like you also can't use the `.ani` format in a content project either. [According to RB Whitaker](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-managing-content) these are the supported image file types for content projects:

`.bmp, .dds, .dib, .hdr, .jpg, .pfm, .png, .ppm, .tga`

It looks like you'll have to manually implement the mouse cursor animation using a spritesheet system.

Hope that helps.